# Environment variable in Windows showing different path

Tags: environment-variables, windows-10

I am trying to keep the value of `M2` variable as different in the Users section but for some reason it's showing me different path over there instead of `%M2_HOME%\bin`. I have tried deleting and entering it again but for some reason it's not changing. I tried restarting my computer as well. Please find the image below :[image]

Could anyone tell me what is the fix?

Comment: You cannot have a user variable dependent upon another user variable. [They can be dependent only on system variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj853254.aspx). My guess is that you have a system variable called `M2_HOME`, and that's the one being used by the user variable `M2`. But note that this question is off topic for Stack Overflow; it belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Okay, I was following this tutorial (Video) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtj-0yhox5s

Comment: @Raymond Thanks for the link. It's confusing because if I create the following user environment variables in the GUI in this sequence: name `A1` set to value `v1`, `A2` = `%A1%`, `A3` =  `%A4%`, `A4` = `v4` (where none of A1..4 existed before in either the user or system environment) then `set` at the cmd prompt lists `A1 = A2 = v1` and `A3 = A4 = v4`. But I guess that's just an artifact of the cmd interpreter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I deleted everything and entered the path  in the value of `Path` variable in System variable. It worked fine in the command prompt.
[image]